# How to return http status 403 on http connection, not on https using Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring mvc and spring security to lock down a webservice. I have restricted all connections to use https using this ...

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

But when I connect over http I don't get http status code 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to intercept creation of [`SecureChannelProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/SecureChannelProcessor.html) (for example, using `BeanPostProcessor`) and supply it with the custom `ChannelEntryPoint` that would send "403 Forbidden".